# How can I determine why I received a Form 1099-G?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I received a 1099-G Tax Document in the mail today.  Is there a way to determine why I got this and what it is related to?

Comment: Brian - What state are you in? An "<insert state> DOR 100-G" search gets explicit information on how/why states administer the form.

Comment: I live in Massachusetts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a refund last year right?  I believe your 1099-G is probably the income from that.  The **G** is *government* income.

Comment: I got a refund, yes.  Should it be equal to the refund or a percentage?  Still confused.

Comment: The form's instructions should explain what's in the boxes.  If it still isn't clear, I've found calling the IRS to be very helpful.

Comment: It is the total dollar amount you were refunded.  It has to be included in your gross income this year (since it wasn't included last year).  There is a spot on your taxes for this number.